# View source code of the native Android email app?

Tags: android, email, inspect-element, nativeapplication

Anybody know a way to view the source code of an email from the native Android email app?

I've used the ADB plugin for the Android chrome browser to inspect element, but wondering if there is something similar for the Android email app.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to view the raw, unformatted contents of an email from within the email client?

Comment: Yes, it's a bit unclear what you're asking for. Do you want the source code for the Email apk that is included as standard in the Android OS (likely written in Java) or are you just hoping to monitor the network requests and responses made by the app?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my apologies for not being clear enough. I'd like the see the HTML that is being generated within a particular email, similar to what the ADB plugin for chrome/android does with inspect element. Looking for the basic HTML (table cells and such). I'm not looking for any of the Java OS code. Hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Save your message as file. An .eml file is saved  in the ,Saved mail -folder on the storage. Use an app like total commander to open the file tekst.